# Prestashop / Google API error 400 invalid_request

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, prestashop, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

I tried to connect the Google Analytics API to my Prestashop 1.6.1.11.

I created and install the Google Analytics, then configure the API Google Anlytics in v3.0 mode ( with OAuth 2.0 ), but each time I put the parameters (`ID Client`, `secret key` and `Profile` ), Google Analytics API redirect me to a 400 error with this message :

> Error: invalid_request / 
>   Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: modules/gapi/oauth2callback.php

I don't understand because when I create the API identification, I put the redirect URI like that :

> http://www.websitename.com/modules/gapi/ouath2callback.php

And same for https, but still doesn't work

Did I miss something ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: please include your code.  And double check that this is the same redirect URI that you put in Google developer console when you created your project and the credentials in question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a relative URI "modules/gapi/oauth2callback.php". It needs to be the full, absolute URI, character for character identical to the URI you defined in the API Console, eg. "https://www.websitename.com/modules/gapi/ouath2callback.php". Also, don't use http for redirect URI. It's only a matter of time before plain text URLs are disabled for security reasons.